# React with Django: Internal Server Error 500

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

**api-service.js**

This is my api code. Using this code, a user can login and do some operations like update, create and delete movies. All functions are working fine except for the *registerUser*.

```
export class API {

    static loginUser(body) {
        return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify( body )
        }).then( resp => resp.json())
    }

    static registerUser(body) {
        return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify( body )
        }).then( resp => resp.json())
    }

    static updateMovie(mov_id, body, token) {
        return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/${mov_id}/`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify( body )
        }).then( resp => resp.json())
    }

    static createMovie(body, token) {
        return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify( body )
        }).then( resp => resp.json())
    }

    static deleteMovie(mov_id, token) {
        return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/${mov_id}/`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Token ${token}`
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**auth.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import  { API } from '../api-service';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';


function Auth(){

    const [ username, setUsername ] = useState('');
    const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');
    const [ isLoginView, setIsLoginView ] = useState(true);

    const  [token, setToken] = useCookies(['mr-token']);

    useEffect( () => {
        if (token['mr-token']) window.location.href = '/movies';
    }, [token])

    const loginClicked = () => {
        API.loginUser({username, password})
        .then( resp => setToken('mr-token', resp.token))
        .catch( error => console.log(error))
    }

    const registerClicked = () => {
        API.registerUser({username, password})
        .then( () => loginClicked())
        .catch( error => console.log(error))
    }


    return (
        <div>
            {isLoginView ? <h1>Login</h1> : <h1>Register</h1>}
            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label><br/>
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" value={username}
                onChange = {evt => setUsername(evt.target.value)}
            /><br/>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label><br/>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" value={password}
                onChange = {evt => setPassword(evt.target.value)} /><br/>
                { isLoginView ? 
                    <button onClick={loginClicked} >Login</button> : 
                    <button onClick={registerClicked} >Register</button>
                }
            { isLoginView ? 
                <p onClick={() => setIsLoginView(false)}>You don't have an account? Register here!</p> : 
                <p onClick={() => setIsLoginView(true)}>You already have an account? Login here!</p>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Auth;
```

**Error-Screenshot**

https://i.imgur.com/pMul9rT.png

I am trying to register the new user in django database but I am getting this error. Please help me out.

Comment: The problem is in the backend... django crash and server returns 500 error. You need share the python code.

Comment: Thanks @kaajavi, I have error in my **views.py** file and now I fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Incorrect: views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Movie, Rating
from .serializers import MovieSerializer, RatingSerializer, UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def rate_movie(self, request, pk=None):
        if 'star' in request.data:

            movie = Movie.objects.get(id=pk)
            star = request.data['star']
            user = request.user

            try:
                rating = Rating.objects.get(user=user.id, movie=movie.id)
                rating.star = star
                rating.save()
                serializer = RatingSerializer(rating, many=False)
                response = {'message': 'rating updated', 'result': serializer.data}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except:
                rating = Rating.objects.create(user=user, movie=movie, star=star)
                serializer = RatingSerializer(rating, many=False)
                response = {'message': 'rating created', 'result': serializer.data}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            response = {'message': 'You need to provide stars'}
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = {'message': 'You cant update rating like that'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = {'message': 'You cant create rating like that'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Correct: views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Movie, Rating
from .serializers import MovieSerializer, RatingSerializer, UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def rate_movie(self, request, pk=None):
        if 'star' in request.data:

            movie = Movie.objects.get(id=pk)
            star = request.data['star']
            user = request.user

            try:
                rating = Rating.objects.get(user=user.id, movie=movie.id)
                rating.star = star
                rating.save()
                serializer = RatingSerializer(rating, many=False)
                response = {'message': 'rating updated', 'result': serializer.data}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except:
                rating = Rating.objects.create(user=user, movie=movie, star=star)
                serializer = RatingSerializer(rating, many=False)
                response = {'message': 'rating created', 'result': serializer.data}
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            response = {'message': 'You need to provide stars'}
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = {'message': 'You cant update rating like that'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = {'message': 'You cant create rating like that'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Answer:**
In my django views.py code,  I just have to add this statement `permission_classes = (AllowAny,)` in class UserViewSet. And the error is gone.

I just want to thank @kaajavi, who told me that I have error in my server side.